# Insert Date logic in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List item in order to display clearly I could visualize the small list follows, that could be hundreds rows. `EndDate` can be `nullable`, if it is null, it means the course still open.

```
CourseId    ClassName    StartDate   EndDate
--------    --------      --------  --------
12321       Math         08-25-2017  12-02-2017
32342       Physics      08-25-2017  12-02-2017
34345       Chemistry    08-25-2017  12-02-2017
25325       Math         01-25-2018     -
44345       Chemistry    01-25-2018     -
```

I have `ClassName` and `Date` to pass to retrieve the corresponding object. I am having difficulty how to implement `Date` parameter into the LINQ

```
public Course GetClassesByNameAndDate(string className, DateTime date, List<Courses> allCourses)
{
    Course course  = allCourses.Where( x=> x.ClassName == className ).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

I want to return corresponding class that is in the given date. For example, if I pass `today date` and also course name as `Math`, then it should return me `25325 courseID` object from the list.

Comment: So what's the logic with `date` here? Are you supposed to retrieve a course where `StartDate < date` and `EndDate == null || EndDate > date`?

Comment: Are you wanting that Where clause to just return courses that are open?

Comment: I want to return corresponding class that is in the given date. For example, if I pass `today date` and also course name as `Math`, then it should return me `25325 courseID` object from the list.

Comment: Read [ask] and elaborate on "having difficulty". Are you looking for `Where(... && x.StartDate <= date && x.EndDate == null)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Course GetClassesByNameAndDate(string className, DateTime date, List<Courses> allCourses)
{
    Course course  = allCourses.Where( x => x.ClassName == className && x.StartDate <= date && x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate.Value >= date : true).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x.StartDate <= date` and `x.EndDate.Value >= date` ?